# How Can I Get a Json File Array From Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Json file containing arrays for instance:

```
{
"Test": ["a","aa","aaa"]
}
```

I want to grab this array through my JavaScript file and use a variable for the json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Node.js, then like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const rawJSON = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf-8')

const data = JSON.parse(rawJSON)
```

Or, you can do:

```
const data = require('./data.json')
```

If you are in the browser, then you need to use your bundler to resolve it in the build step.

Something like webpack may be able to do that just with this code.

Comment: do I delete the `'./ '` in `'./data.json'` and change the name to mine or do I keep the `./` and change the name? sorry I figured it out